# Left align Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just trying to align this form to the left side but I can't. I've tried adding left-align to certain parts of the CSS but nothing. If you could also explain how I can align my form to the left for future reference.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jW8y/5/embedded/result/

Here's the CSS:

```
.grid {
padding: 20px 20px 100x 20px;
max-width: 1300px;
margin: 0 auto;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Center horizontally? Looks fine to me.

Comment: @j08691 Yes. Actually it sort of looks fine but when I publish it to my site it's like 50px to the right.

Comment: Tried adding `padding:0` to your `.grid` class?

Comment: @j08691 That doesn't work either.

Comment: Side note, you have a typo in the padding above: 100x should be 100px.

Comment: @j08691 I saw but It doesn't really affect the code any. I'm trying to left align the code but it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.grid {
    padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

firstly, padding missing the `p` in `100x`, should be `100px`

second, no need `margin: 0 auto`, it will make the ul center if margin-left & right is auto.

finally, (optional) no need `text-align` in this layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    .grid {
        padding: 20px 20px 100x 20px;
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        list-style: none;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

`margin:0 auto`  and `max-width:1300px` from `.grid` class and add

```
width:930px
```

Check this fiddle >http://jsfiddle.net/7jW8y/9/